# using 'this' references with meteor.template.rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

suppose I have a Meteor template called message, where the client can post messages. the post is wrapped in a div that gets an id equal to its unique id in the Mongo collection.

```
<template name="message">
<div class="msg comment" id="{{this._id}}">{{msg}}</div>
</template>
```

is there anyway to reference the specific id in  `Meteor.message.rendered`? right now I am using `this._id` and it's not working. Here is my function

```
Template.message.rendered = function() {
texts = $('this._id').html();
texts = texts.replace(/#(\w+)/g, 
"<a href='https://www.google.com/?q=$1'target='_blank'>$&</a>");
$("this._id").html(texts);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four things:

- You're using a string instead of the variable: `$('this._id')` -> `$(this._id)`
- The context (`this`) of the rendered function is a template helper, and not the data itself (which is the context of the template), so replace `this._id` with `this.data._id` to match `{{ this._id }}`
- It's an ID selector : `$(this.data._id)` -> `$('#' + this.data._id)`
- Rendered callbacks run whenever the template is rerendered, and whenever a subtemplate (a template contained within the template) is rendered, so you should flag when it has been rendered ([source](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/44771047946/using-meteors-rendered-callback), interesting article about meteor rendered).

Final code :

```
Template.message.rendered = function() {
    if(!this.rendered) {
        this.rendered = true;
        texts = $('#' + this.data._id).html();
        texts = texts.replace(/#(\w+)/g,"<a href='https://www.google.com/?q=$1'target='_blank'>$&</a>");
        $('#' + this.data._id).html(texts);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe i'm implementing this wrong, but this is targeting every message with class `msg` (every message). i am trying to manipulate specific messages as opposed to all of them at once

Comment: Edited my answer for something more specific to your use case.